# iOS 9 : Safe Area Layout Programmatically and Remove Side Space in View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9.3

How to add safe area layout to my app for **iPhone 5S** and **iOS 9.3.5**. 
my code is like this

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *))
    {
        loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame];
        [self.view addSubview:loginView];
        loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
        [loginView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.layoutFrame];
        [self.view addSubview:loginView];
        loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        UILayoutGuide *margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide;
        [viloginViewew.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:margins.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:margins.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
        [loginView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;

    }
```

I tried to run in my device but safe area layout show some space in side left and right. I want to remove that space so it will show in full width.

And the height I got from layoutMarginsGuide is too long so it being hidden from view. how to get the proper height of layoutMarginsGuide ?

Do i implement a code wrong ? What should i have to do ?

Comment: just remove the self.view.layoutMarginsGuide to self.view

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me for iPhone 5s. It is covering all space. Use it for iOS below 11.

```
[self.view addConstraints:@[
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0]
                            ]]
```

Comment: I got warning like this "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. "

Comment: it look like the view is really full, no left and right space but also top too. my top view is in behind time, battery status right now. I want my top view is not in behind time, battery status .

Comment: set top constant  to 20, the second constraint, status bar will be visible